# if mysql table name is change then link name is change

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How To do

if table name is change then link name is change

example i have two table with union

```
$constructs ="(SELECT * FROM sales_media WHERE user_name='$row->user_name')
UNION
  (SELECT * FROM rent_media WHERE user_name='$row->user_name') 
ORDER BY City DESC, ID DESC";
```

suppose it is showing two table result together
if sales_media table result found then link is showing sales

like this

```
echo "<a href='sales_".urlencode(str_replace(' ', '_', $project_title))."-$id.html'>$project_title</a></div>";
```

if rent_media table result found then link is showing rent

```
echo "<a href='rent_".urlencode(str_replace(' ', '_', $project_title))."-$id.html'>$project_title</a></div>";
```

how can i do this 
help me to fix this issue

thanks

Comment: what are the structure of these two tables?

Comment: Have you tried a left join? Left join will show all results even if one value is not found in another table

Answer (score 0):

It took me 4 reads to figure out what you want to do but I think that I have finally understood

You should add a "marker" in your 2 `SELECT` in order to know from which table the rows comes from.

In my example below I alias the "marker" as `typerow`

```
$constructs ="(SELECT 'sales_row' AS typerow, * FROM sales_media WHERE user_name='$row->user_name')
UNION
  (SELECT 'rent_row' AS typerow, * FROM rent_media WHERE user_name='$row->user_name') 
ORDER BY City DESC, ID DESC";
```

then you cand do something  like

```
if ($row->typerow=='sales_row'){
    echo "<a href='sales_".urlencode(str_replace(' ', '_', $project_title))."-$id.html'>$project_title</a></div>";  
}else{
    echo "<a href='rent_".urlencode(str_replace(' ', '_', $project_title))."-$id.html'>$project_title</a></div>";                                                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that in your queries:

```
$constructs <<<EOT
(SELECT 'sales' AS type, * FROM sales_media WHERE user_name='{$row->user_name}')
UNION
(SELECT 'rent' AS type, * FROM rent_media WHERE user_name='{$row->user_name}') 
ORDER BY City DESC, ID DESC"
EOT;
```

That way you can see in each row in the result set what table that entry comes from. Now it is easy to implement a conditional based on that information:

```
echo sprintf(
    '<a href="%s_%s-%s.html">%s</a></div>',
    $newRow['type'], 
    urlencode(str_replace(' ', '_', $project_title)),
    $id,
    htmlescape($project_title)
);
```

However this looks like a hack of some kind. A typical situation where one should take a closer look at the database scheme and ask if there is an issue there. Why aren't those entries kept in the same table, if they have the same structure and semantic?